# After Using Elipse IDE to deploy a package to another org. App not showing up in app menu

Tags: metadata-api, package, app, tab, deployment

I used Eclipse IDE to deploy a package created in one organisation to another organization. After successfully deploying to another organisation, I am able to see all the components of the package in the new org, except that they are not in working condition.
App/Application is not showing up in APP menu.
    I fixed it by editing the app and assigning profiles to it.
Now the App shows up in APP menu, but after switching to the app, the tabs present in the app are not showing up.

Am I missing anything? How to make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that the visibility for the tabs has not been set yet. You could try setting the tab visibility on the profiles to `DefaultOn` using the metadata api or through the user interface. By default when creating a new tab through a deployment, they are `Hidden` for all profiles you don't specify a different value for.